# .textContent not working on a cloned node

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to clone a DOM element and then replace the text inside of it. Here is a very simple example.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rmZbPR

The issue is that the cloning appears to prevent .textContent (or .innerHTML) from working. I get the following error...

```
Uncaught TypeError: pCloned.textContent is not a function
```

Any pointers would be much appreciated.

```js
var p = document.getElementById('para');
var pCloned = p.cloneNode(true);

// Remove this to see that the clone works correctly
pCloned.textContent('This is a cloned paragraph');

document.getElementById('list').appendChild(pCloned);
```

```html
<p id="para">This is a paragraph</p>

<div id="list"></div>
```

Comment: The error message is **really** clear: `textContent` is not a function. It's a property. I suggest doing your basic research before posting. For instance, this is the top hit for the search "textContent" on both DuckDuckGo and Google: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`textContent` is not a function, but a simple get/set string property. Correct it to this:

```
pCloned.textContent = 'This is a cloned paragraph';
```